# Can't display categories under category type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, has-and-belongs-to-many, model-associations

I have two different models category and category type i just want to display categories under category type but i don't know how.

I’m using has_many and belongs_to association where the category has a foreign key 'categorytype_id' 
I've tried but every time it displays the category type with just one category

Index.html.erb

```
 <% @categories.each do |category| %>
 <% =category.categorytype.label %>
 <% =category.label %>
 <% end %>
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ads
  belongs_to :categorytype
end
```

categorytype.rb

```
class Categorytype < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories
end
```

i want to display all categories that belongs to that specified category type without repetition

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to find what you getting in params? & please show your association here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CategoryType has many categories, so it should be

```
<% @category_types.each do |category_type| %>
  <%= category_type.label
  <% category_type.categories.map do |category| %>
    <%= category.label %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You'll loop through each CategoryType, display the label, then display associated categories